# Nominalization of Conditionals to Use With 気がつく (realize)

Tags: conditionals, nominalization

First question on this Japanese sub-community. Sorry if this confusing or hard to explain. Basically, I want to say

> Everyone should realize that if the YouTube thumbnail wasn't a picture of an anime girl, there wouldn't be 1 million views.

but get stuck on "that if". I'm not sure whether to nominalize the conditional part before adding in 気がつく (realize), or something else. Wasn't sure where to put the "realize" phrase, but here was my best shot:

> YouTubeサムネールはアニメの女の子の写真でなければ１００万視聴回数がない気がすべきつく。

Comment: If you choose to write 気がつく in kanji, it would usually be 気が付く, not \*気が着く.

Answer (score 1):

You can say ことに気が付くべきだ or のに気が付くべきだ.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on what you've written, though I might not be 100% correct.

1 - Be aware of tenses. You're talking about a state of being from the past (**wasn't** a picture) affecting the present (**be** 1 million).

> YouTubeサムネールはアニメの女の子の写真**ではなかったら**１００万視聴回数がない気がすべきつく。

2 - Grammar. I've never seen 気がすべきつく before. I think you mean 気がつくべきです, but it still should be all wrapped in a こと.

> YouTubeサムネールはアニメの女の子の写真**ではなかったら**１００万視聴回数がない**ことに気がつくべきです**。

3 - It still seems incorrect to me for some reason... The usage of **は** on YouTube seems like you're asking YouTube itself to take notice. I might be wrong, but this seems more logical to me:

> YouTube**の**サムネール**が**アニメの女の子の写真**ではなかったら**１００万**の**視聴回数**を達成できないことに気がつくべきです**。

Comment: 1 vote for all the grammatical requirements explained except "everyone" = みな (though It'd be closer to the original sentence with 視聴回数(が)１００万もなかった or so).

Answer (score 0):

I think the translation you are looking for is:

> YouTubeサムネールはアニメの女の子の写真でなければ、１００万視聴回数がないことに誰もが気づくはず。

Note the use of はず (the speaker's expectations) vs. your original べき (duty).

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> １００万視聴回数がない**こと**に**気がつくべき**。

- realize → 気がつく。We don't use 気がすべき.
- should → 〜すべき, 〜べき.

The word order: 気がつく べき.
... And it need こと. (I feel odd if there is no こと)